# Engineering Application with Integration

Tags: integration, applications

[image: link]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/175e0115b9411d3baeb08fa5795d9c90.png?1359482363))</sub>

I need help for part $(i)$ ... What I think I know so far:

$P = dgh = (1000)(9.8)(h)$

Finding $h$:

- We will choose an arbitrary value '$x$' somewhere between $0$ and $3$.
- The height of this "plane" is $3-x$.
- Unfortunately, the volume is difficult to calculate because $r$ is a function of $x$.
- We will need to create a formula that relates $r$ as $x$ increases. This is possibly modeled by
  $r(x)=\sqrt{25-x^2}$

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The $3$ is really not relevant at this stage, it will only come into play when you are choosing the limits of integration.

Draw a **vertical** cross-section that goes through the centre $C$ of the hemisphere.  You have probably already done this. It is essential.

The distance from $C$ to the centre of the circle of radius $r$ we are curious about is $5-x$. The distance from $C$ to the edge of that circle is $5$. So by the Pythagorean Theorem, we have $(5-x)^2+r^2=5^2$. That yields $r^2=10x-x^2$. So the area of our circle of radius $r$ is $\pi(10x-x^2)$.

That answers your question about $r$. We will need to lift that slice through a distance $6-x$, so your integrand will ultimately be a constant times $(6-x)(10x-x^2)$.